# I get an error while trying to run a class about a main method not being found in the class

Tags: eclipse, methods, program-entry-point, slick2d

```
Error: Main method not found in class Menu, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
```

I always get that error and I tried to put that everywhere in the code but it just won't run...I'm using Slick2D for a menu.

Here's my code for the `Menu` class.

```
import org.newdawn.slick.Image;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Menu {

    Image background = null;
    Image startGameOption = null;
    Image exitOption = null;

    float startGameScale = 1;
    float exitScale = 1; {

        try {
            background = new Image("Sprites/MenuBackground.gif");
        } catch (SlickException e1) {       
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // load the menu images
        Image menuOptions;
        try {
            menuOptions = new Image("Sprites/MenuOptions.gif");
        } catch (SlickException e) {    
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        startGameOption = menuOptions.getSubImage(0, 0, 377, 71);

        exitOption = menuOptions.getSubImage(0, 71, 377, 71);
    }
}
```

I'm also using Eclipse. I can never make it stop giving that error though..that's the only error that comes up when I try to run the `Menu` class. I checked everywhere and it doesn't seem to help me get through this error.

Answer (score 1):

Every application that you want to run must have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method.  As written at the time I am viewing this, you don't have *any* methods at all.  You just have a "block" of code.

I'd suggest try to put the `public static void main(String[] args)` between the `float exitScale = 1;` and the `{` on the same line.  Without studying the rest of your code too closely, it looks like you will still have fairly broken code, but I think it should get you past the first problem you are having.

And then go back and read chapter 1 of any Java book to review the requirements of a Java program, and what a method is.